# When I insert into a table, how do I create a trigger such that the inserted numeric value is summed up in another table's column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

I have a table `CabinCrew` and another table `Employee`. The `CabinCrew` table, among other things, records the `FlightHours` of the crew for a particular flight.

`CabinCrew(EmployeeID, FlightID, Hours)`

`Employee(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Email, JobTitle, FlightHours)`

`EmployeeID` is the primary key of the `Employee` table and both the primary and foreign key of the `CabinCrew` table.

The `Employee` table also has an attribute `FlightHours`, which is the total flying hours for the crew. How do I create a trigger such that an entry in the `CabinCrew` table, triggers an update on the `Employee` table which adds the `FlightHours` from `CabinCrew` to the total flight hours in the Employee table?

Comment: without knowing the diewsgn how can we combine both table to get the right employee see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk I have added details on the 2 tables now

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with **YOUR** attempt at a solution and the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt. StackOverflow is not a free coding service and you are not going to learn if you don't attempt to solve **YOUR** homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an AFTERT INSERT trigger.

```
CREATE TABLe CabinCrew (EmployeeID int, FlightID int, Hours int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeID int , FirstName varchar2(50)
  , LastName varchar2(50), Email varchar2(50), JobTitle varchar2(50), FlightHours int)
```

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(1,'test1','test2','test@test.com','job1',0)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CabinCrew_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON CabinCrew
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   V_EMPLOYEEID int;
BEGIN
   SELECT "EMPLOYEEID" INTO V_EMPLOYEEID FROM Employee WHERE "EMPLOYEEID" = :new.EMPLOYEEID;
IF V_EMPLOYEEID IS NULL THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Employee unknown');
END if;
  UPDATE Employee SET FLIGHTHOURS = FLIGHTHOURS + :new.HOURS
    WHERE "EMPLOYEEID" = :new.EMPLOYEEID;
END CabinCrew_after_insert;
/
```

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

```
INSERT INTO CabinCrew VALUEs(1,1,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO CabinCrew VALUEs(2,1,1)
```

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_HHVVQEUNGIIOLEAXDXQH.CABINCREW_AFTER_INSERT", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_HHVVQEUNGIIOLEAXDXQH.CABINCREW_AFTER_INSERT'
```

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

| EMPLOYEEID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | EMAIL | JOBTITLE | FLIGHTHOURS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | test2 | test@test.com | job1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VzOJ00G8)

Comment: The OP should be using a referential constraint to enforce that an Employee exists and not a `SELECT` clause in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The [`CREATE TRIGGER` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html) gives you details of the syntax of a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

To solve your problem, you need:

- A trigger on the `CabinCrew` table.
- That triggers on `UPDATE` and `INSERT` (and, maybe `DELETE`) and `FOR EACH ROW` modified.
- Then in the body of the trigger you need to `UPDATE` the `Employee` table for the modified `EmployeeId` and add the new `Hours` (which will be `NULL` for a delete statement) and subtract the old `Hours` (which will be `NULL` for an insert statement) from the existing flight hours.